# how to find unique values from two different columns in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

i am facing this issue right now. i hope someone will help me out. i want to find the unique values from the range column A to column D.

Comment: Your edits have made this question very vague, and you have not commented on whether the two earlier answers have been helpful on your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the ranges by using curly brackets ({}) and then surround that with the `UNIQUE()` function.

`=UNIQUE({A:A;B:B;C:C;D:D})`

edit: changed comma separator to semi-comma. The comma adds arrays together as columns while semi-comma adds them into one column.

Comment: hi @a-burge... i am facing one more situation now.. pls take a look.. hope u will help me.

Comment: Please, vote on the best answer for your question.  It is a way to say thank you for peole who had spent time trying to help you.  Also, create a New tópic if you have a diffenlrent problem.  Take care.

Comment: The note on using comma vs semicolon was helpful to me (when paired with the note on using curly braces). Thanks!

Comment: @Dannid if you're interested in more documentation, please see this article by Ben: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/arrays-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

The best way for your database is:

`=sort(UNIQUE({A2:A;B2:B;C2:C;D2:D}))`

I just change what @a-burge has done.  He has to take the credit for that!

- He forgot to use `(` when he typed here.   Of course, he will edit it.
- Also, I had used `sort()` function.
- `sort()` function is used to set data in A-Z order.  But also take some blank spaces out!

Long-life to Stack Overflow.