# Sorting and merging two columns in Google Sheets without whitespace: what's the solution?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My sheet

[image: my sheet]

What I want to do is simply combine these 2 rows of columns with different info like fish type and merge them into the column on the right where it says both, I managed to combine them but it has all the white spaces and I also need it to be sorted alphabetically.

I have tried fiddling with some filter functions but I am a bit clueless, just a bunch of errors

Comment: I have created this read-only sheet for this question. see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wf5Za_TuiPYTa25gJIhCouYaxiy70XLK6EhasmKzsHg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find unique values from two different columns in google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557330/how-to-find-unique-values-from-two-different-columns-in-google-sheet)

Comment: No sorry I need all values not just unique ones!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula-

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(FLATTEN(A3:A,C3:C),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: I need them all entries! Not just unqiue values, I forgot to specify sorry, do I just remove the unique tag for that?

Comment: @Dav Yes, just remove `UNIQUE()` function. Try `=SORT(TOCOL(FLATTEN(A3:A,C3:C),1))`.

Comment: Im getting an error when trying to use it in my sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ZU6CowQ_2CEMhvworkkrWJ_NcdlNvi-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109507627592554463957&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: At the "old burg lake" tab

Comment: Are you on Excel or google-sheet? They are two different product.

Comment: If you are on `Microsoft Excel 365` then use `=SORT(VSTACK(TOCOL(C7:C50000,1),TOCOL(L7:L50000,1)))`.